# How to set JAVA_HOME correctly on CentOS?

Tags: centos, java, jdk

I am trying to set **JAVA_HOME** so that I can **install Apache Solr** with the help of this **[tutorial](https://www.cocking.com/2015/03/30/apache-solr-5-0-install-on-centos-7/)**. I am connected to my server using **ssh** with **root user**

To allow the running sh script to install Apache Solr:

```
mount | grep noexec
```

Re-mounting file system with exec option:

```
mount -o remount,exec /dev/md1
```

Then every time I try to install it using the following commands

```
bin/install_solr_service.sh /tmp/solr-5.3.1.tgz
```

I get the following message:

```
WARNING: /opt/solr-5.3.1 already exists! Skipping extract ...

Creating /etc/init.d/solr script ...
The currently defined JAVA_HOME (/usr/local/jdk) refers
to a location where Java could not be found.  Aborting.
Either fix the JAVA_HOME variable or remove it from the
environment so that the system PATH will be searched.
The currently defined JAVA_HOME (/usr/local/jdk) refers
to a location where Java could not be found.  Aborting.
Either fix the JAVA_HOME variable or remove it from the
environment so that the system PATH will be searched.
Service solr installed.
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
nano /root/.bash_profile 
nano /etc/profile
```

I added the following to the files above at the end and saved them

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

That didn't work.

I created the following file /etc/profile.d/java.sh and put in it:

```
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre/
export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And ran the following command:

```
source java.sh
```

That also didn't work.

I tried to run the following command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64
```

No luck at all.

But when a run the following commands that is what I get

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre//bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: Where is ths problem? I don't see any java errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading my question and found the answer in it. This is what I have done:

I have undone all the changes to **/root/.bash_profile** and **/etc/profile**

Then I created a folder called **jdk** in the /usr/local/ folder like so

```
mkdir /usr/local/jdk
```

Since this is were the jdk is expected to be located in. Then I copied the jdk files to that newcp -R /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre/* /usr/local/jdk/ folder like so:

```
cp -R /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre/* /usr/local/jdk/
```

As simple as that I was now able to install Apache Solr

Comment: cp -R will destroy attributes, use cp -a.

Answer (score 15):

You want to point JAVA_HOME to the JRE directory, as in:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

If using bash, I recommend putting this in `/etc/bashrc` (RH based) or `/etc/bash.bashrc` (Debian based):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/bin/java::")
```

Comment: Assuming you have a link for Java here. This is more a Debian specific thing, please change accordingly for CentOS

Comment: CentOS 7 here, works.

Comment: This worked for me only after overwriting JAVA_HOME inside `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: @ovi I am using Debian, what is your distro?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Centos 6.7. Maybe it's also worth mentioning that `/etc/bashrc` already contained following:  `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk` 
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` 
`export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip`

Comment: Thanks @ovi, I am changing the answer from /etc/profile to /etc/bashrc as it is more compatible with bash.

Comment: cool, glad I could help. maybe you can also remove the trailing slash from the directory, so no double slashes appear when using it to form new paths? e.g. use `sed "s:/bin/java::"`

Comment: It has not done any difference for me in years, or perhaps I did not notice. Changed; will check out later on more about that, thanks. (I am not a Java developer, thanks for the pointers)

Comment: Usually JAVA_HOME points to JDK, not JRE - [Should JAVA_HOME point to JDK or JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601827/should-java-home-point-to-jdk-or-jre)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying out files from the installation directory it would be better to set the `SOLR_JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` to the location of the `jre` folder in your installation such as `usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-0.b17.el6_7.x86_64/jre/`